# FSBTool error on importing audio file in unity (Mac)

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

When I try to import my background music, which is a .wav file, unity console is printing following error:
Errors during import of AudioClip Assets/Sounds/Musics/SpaceMusic1.wav:
FSBTool ERROR: The format of the source file is invalid; see output for details

I tried few methods, which includes rebooting, using ffmpeg, reimporting, but none of them worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.